# Meteor Release Version Error When Attempting to Start Server

Tags: meteor

When trying to start the meteor server I get the following error:

```
This project says that it uses Meteor release <<<<<<< METEOR@1.0.2.1 >>>>>>>, but you don't have that version of Meteor installed and the Meteor update servers don't have it either. Please edit the .meteor/release file in the project
```

I have updated to 1.0.2.1 and the .meteor/release file in the project is reflecting that. The other interesting thing is that when I attempt to pull the version `meteor -v` I am thrown the same error. I am running Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: What do you get if you run `meteor --version` in a directory that does not contain a meteor project?

Comment: I do indeed get 1.0.2.1.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Meteor?

Comment: I have not, that will be my next course of action.

Answer (score 1):

from within the project folder:

```
meteor update --release METEOR@1.0.2.1
```

or if you're using a different version of meteor

```
meteor update --release METEOR@[insert version here]
```